# How to Command-X files on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: mac, macos

I noticed that Command-X (cut and paste) is greyed out on finder in El Capitan.
Is there any way to get it back?

EDIT: WITHOUT Command-Option-V.
If possible, way to map command-option-v to command-x would be great....

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the file as normal with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and then when you past use
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and it will paste the file, and also cut it from its original location